# Linker error with Boost Threads in C++ in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, multithreading, boost

I have been trying to get a simple c++ program running that was given to me as an example of multi-thread programming. I know it runs on another machine with boost installed, but I am trying to run it in Xcode, and this is giving me some problems.

First I tried to run it with my existing version of boost. However I was getting many errors and after doing some research, found that I needed to update my boost version from 1.47 to 1.52 to fix a few known threading bugs contained in 1.47.

That fixed many of my errors, but was still throwing a few. SO I found out that I had to patch 1.52 using the patch found here: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/attachment/ticket/7671/libcpp_c11_numeric_limits.patch

After all that, I am still getting a linker error saying "Library not found for -lboost_thread"

Right now in Xcode, I have the following project settings: 
Under search paths, I have the header and library search paths set to "usr/local/include/" - - Under linking I have other linker flags set to "-lboost_thread"

I have both a lboost_thread.a and a lboost_thread.dylib located in usr/local/lib/. How do I make xCode find this, as It seems that should fix my problem.

Also if it helps here is the code I am running:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using namespace std;

void printNum(char c, int num)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        cout << c << i << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Boost threads!" << endl;
    boost::thread t(printNum, 'b', 100);
    printNum('a', 100);
    cout << "Good bye!" << endl;
}
```

Image of Error:
[image: Error]

Image showing the file in it's location:
[image: libboost_thread.a]

Image showing my build settings:
[image: xCode build settings]

Comment: If you're using a recent version of Xcode you can set the standard library to libc++ and use the C++11 `<thread>` library instead of boost.

Comment: You say you have lboost_thread.a and lboost_thread.dylib.  The names should be libboost_thread.a and libboost_thread.dylib.

Comment: @JWWalker They are, I just typed them wrong.

Comment: @bames53 I am required to use boost for my thread assignments, so I am just trying to get it working on xCode.

Comment: And when you say the libraries are in usr/local/lib, you mean /usr/local/lib, right?  Show us the exact command line being fed to the linker.  Assuming Xcode 4.5, you can find this in the Log Navigator.

Comment: @JWWalker Image of the error from the Log Navigator is now in the original question.

Comment: It seems like those files aren't where you think they are.  What output do you get from entering `file /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.a` at the Terminal command line?

Comment: @JWWalker Last login: Mon Dec  3 20:20:20 on ttys000
Users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ file /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.a
/usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.a: current ar archive random library
Users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.a
-bash: /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.a: Permission denied
Users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the linker isn't finding the library, but I can tell you how to circumvent the issue of library search:  Add the full path `/usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.a` to the Other Linker Flags build setting, without -l or -L.

Comment: Tried this, but still no dice. I have updated my question with both pictures of the file in it's location, and what I changed my build settings to. Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your image shows the build settings at the project level.  Target level build settings override project level, so make sure the settings you want aren't getting overridden.  (By the way, it doesn't make sense to use /usr/local/include as a library search path, but I don't think that's a significant problem.)

Comment: Still not working. Also I just compiled this in the command line to make sure it was working there, and got it to compile with "g++ -g -Wall -lboost_thread -lboost_system -o test dijkstras.cc" I have tried adding both -lboost_thread and -lboost_system to the other linker flags section of the target level and still throwing the same error.

Comment: Exact same error as before(image in original question), even if I add the path. It can't find -lboost_system either. It errors out with whatever one I add to the other linker section first.

Comment: I don't understand how it could be the same error if you're not saying -lboost_thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot says `/usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.a` the advice is to use `-I/usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.a` maybe that is the thing.